# Can I re-wire 2-6pin 2-position rocker switches with a single rocker switch?

Tags: switches

I have an older 12v power wheel that the forward and reverse are controlled by 2 6-pin rocker switches as shown in the following image. [image: direction box]

When the lever is pulled/pushed, it flips the switches.

The newer power wheel is a 6v that I’ve gutted and swapping the motors and wiring from the 12v body into the 6v body.

The 6v fwd and reverse is controlled by a single rocker switch (obviously). My question is, can I use a single 2-position rocker switch to control both motors? I’m trying to do all of this without having to cut the body to make the old parts fit, if that makes sense.

The only marking on the 2 old rocker switches (other than a 48/2006, which may be the date stamp) is an 8T & 12V, as shown:

[image: old rocker switches]

Here’s the rocker switch from the 6v body:

[image: 6v rocker switch image 1]

[image: 6v rocker switch image 2]

My though was that I can connect the matching pin wires to the respective ones on the single rocker switch but only connect one power wire.

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: You need to draw the schematic and report what maximum current flows are. Please also link to the data sheets of the rocker switches. Please also state whether the operating voltage is AC or DC. I have no idea what a power wheel is BTW.

Comment: "power wheel" what's that?

Comment: @jasen rideable kid sized toy car

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the wiring is as shown in that last picture, then no, you could not directly replace the 3 states of the 2 switches with a single DPDT switch with 2 states.

You could ignore the high/low feature and just wire the two motors in parallel, so you get just reverse and forward. Or ignore reverse/forward and wire the high/low function (series vs parallel motors).

Otherwise you need to cut in to add one of those switches. You could try finding a 3 position switch in that form factor but it's not likely and you'll still have to find a way to integrate it into the new mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, without seeing wiring diagrams of the two systems.

However, it looks to me, based on your first photo, that in the two-switch system, that the switches are used as single-throw types, with one closed for forward, and the other closed for reverse.  Both switches would be open for "Stop".

With a single switch, you would need a three position (center off) switch to provide a stop function as well as forward and reverse.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately I don’t have access to the wiring diagram only the following: https://imgur.com/a/zNnxFZT. I do see now that my two way switch won’t work but, was able to find a 3 position that looks like the same dimensions.

Comment: Looking at that wiring diagram, it appears that I mis-guessed the functions of that controller.  You won't need a center-off switch as the throttle switch will handle the "Stop" function, but you do still need separate forward-reverse and fast/slow switches, althoug you could omit the fast/slow switch if you are only need one speed range.

Comment: Thank you! I have a game plan now. I really appreciate your response and time. Happy holidays!